# Copy & Paste cells from one sheet to another, in a row

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA Code that moves specific cells from one sheet (lets just call it Sheet1 in the code as well), cells need copying: AA5, AA6, AA7, AA8 & AA10.

The cells needs that are copied need to be pasted, in a row, to an another sheet (sheet2)(AA5 - A, AA6 -B, AA7 - D, AA8 - F, & AA10 - G) Obviously, With A, B, etc. I mean the column in sheet2.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and provide a [mcve] of what you've tried so far. This is a ridiculously trivial macro which can be produced entirely with Excel's "Record Macro" feature. Have you tried that?

Comment: Unfortunately, my post has been eddited which doesnt show my issue to the fullest. I understand this can be done with a simple and single macro. However, each time i click the button the copied cells have to go down a row in sheet2. So you 'register' the entered values in a table.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy cell A1 for example from Sheet1 to Sheet2

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

If you want to copy more than 1 cell, create a function

```
Sub paste()
     Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
     Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
     Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value
End Sub
```

Then call you method like this :

```
Call paste()
```

Let me know for more informations

Or maybe you trying to do this :

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value & "," & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

However, this would just paste in the same cells in sheet 2 over & over and not put them in a row?

Comment: If you want to put them on AA57 you just have to change the "A1" value

Comment: Example to put cell A1 of Sheet1 to AA57 of Sheet2 :
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("AA57").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

Comment: Thanks again. Issue still: All the copied items should be put in to a row on sheet2 everytime you press the assigned button without modifying the Macro. AFAIK this is done with the Offset, but I have no idea how to add it.. ;(

Comment: Can you explain me more the problem, can't understand the need. (And not familiar with English)

Comment: Look at the response i added something than may helps you

Comment: I have to try that out tomorrow, as im not at work anymore. It needs to enter a new row everytime you click the button on the 2nd sheet btw